# run javascript for all rows in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, html-table

i am trying to run the jscript for all rows in an HTML table after fetching the data from MySQL database. Doing this in MVC using codeigniter. 
Instead of getting the calculated values through javascript for all rows, i am just getting the first row.
Please help me out!

here's the code

```
<table id="myTable" border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>date</td>
        <td>client ID</td>
        <td>client Name</td>
        <td>Bill Amount</td>
        <td>VAT(%)</td>
        <td>Service Charge(Client)</td>
        <td>Service Charge(IDK)</td>
        <td>Subtotal</td>
        <td>Service Charge(FoodHive)</td>
        <td>Delivery Charge(FoodHive)</td>
        <td>Service Tax(FoodHive)</td>
        <td>TDS</td>
        <td>Net Service Charge</td>
        <td>Net Amount</td>
    </tr>

<?php
foreach ($h->result() as $row) {?>

    <tr id="row1">
    <td><?php echo $row->order_raised_at;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->client_id;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->client_name;?></td>
    <td name="billAmount" id="billAmount"><?php echo $row->bill_amount;?></td>
    <td name="VAT" id="VAT"><?php echo $row->VAT;?></td>
    <td name="serviceChargeClient" id="serviceChargeClient"><?php echo $row->service_charge_client; ?></td>
    <td name="serviceChargeClientIDK" id="serviceChargeClientIDK"><?php echo $row->service_charge_client_idk; ?></td>
    <td name="subtotal" id="subtotal">&nbsp;</td>
    <td name="serviceChargeFH" id="serviceChargeFH"><?php echo $row->service_charge_fh;?></td>
    <td name="deliveryChargeFH" id="deliveryChargeFH">&nbsp;</td>
    <td name="serviceTaxFH" id="serviceTaxFH"><?php echo $row->service_tax_fh;?></td>
    <td name="TDS" id="TDS"><?php echo $row->TDS;?></td>
    <td name = "netServiceCharge" id="netServiceCharge">&nbsp;</td>
    <td name="netAmount" id="netAmount">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<script>
var bill  = $('#billAmount').text(); //220
            var vatpercent = $('#VAT').text(); //12.5%
            var servclient = $('#serviceChargeClient').text(); //10%
            var servidk = $('#serviceChargeClientIDK').text(); //5.6
            var servfhpercent = $('#serviceChargeFH').text(); //15%
            var servtaxfh = $('#serviceTaxFH').text(); //14
            var tds = $('#TDS').text(); //0

            var vat = (vatpercent/100)*bill; 
            var subtotal = bill-vat-servclient-servidk; 
            var servfh = (servfhpercent/100)*subtotal; //26.535
            var netserv = parseFloat(servfh)+parseFloat(servtaxfh);
            var netamount = bill-netserv;

            $('#subtotal').text(subtotal);
            $('#deliveryChargeFH').text(servfh);
            $('#netServiceCharge').text(netserv);
            $('#netAmount').text(netamount);
</script>
<?php } ?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

values like bill_amount, VAT, service_charge, service_charge_fh etc. are already stored in a database for respective clients. the code gets these values from db in the table for client side calculations using js, to calculate:

subtotal,
delivery_charge,
net_service_charge,
net_amount

**controller**

```
<?php
class select extends CI_Controller{

  public function index(){

    $this->load->database(); //load database
    $this->load->model('select_model');
    $data['h'] = $this->select_model->select(); //load model method
    $this->load->view('select_view' , $data);

    }
 }?>
```

**model**

```
<?php

class select_model extends CI_Model{

  function __construct(){

    parent:: __construct();
}

  public function select(){
     $orderDate = $_POST['order_date'];
     $yourDate = date("Y-m-d" , strtotime($orderDate));
     $clientName = $_POST['clientName'];
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT client_orders.order_raised_at, client_orders.bill_amount, client_orders.client_id, 
                                client_orders.client_name, client_charges.VAT, client_charges.service_charge_client,client_orders.subtotal,
                                client_charges.service_charge_client_idk, client_charges.service_charge_fh, client_charges.service_tax_fh,
                                client_charges.TDS from client_orders INNER JOIN client_charges 
                                ON client_orders.client_id = client_charges.client_ID where client_orders.client_name = '$clientName' 
                                AND client_orders.order_raised_at = '$yourDate'");
    return $query;  


    }
  }



?>
```

Comment: just as info: if you do not have any custom logic in your constructor, you don't have to explicitly call the parent constructor with `parent::__construct()`. just omit the whole function declaration.

Comment: Can you please more elaborate what are you asking and what you want to do?

Comment: thanks for telling me that @Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td name="subtotal" id="subtotal">&nbsp;</td>
```

to like these::

```
<td name="subtotal" id="subtotal">
<?php 
 echo (0+$row->bill_amount) - (((0+$row->VAT)/100)*(0+$row->bill_amount)) - (0+$row->service_charge_client) - (0+$row->service_charge_client_idk);
?>
</td>
```

No need of script to do calculation,If you are not using the unique id for  to get it's inner html value. otherwise use @Sergiu Paraschiv method.

Comment: that does it for getting all the subtotal as it is calculated using the values VAT, service_charge_client, service_charge_client_idk from the database. But rest of the fields <td> deliveryChargeFH, netServiceCharge, netAmount are calculated using subtotal which is not on database. how to do that? @Prem Bikram Limbu

Comment: Are you kidding me? rest of the fields <td> deliveryChargeFH, netServiceCharge, netAmount are calculated using subtotal which is not on database can also be done using my method. That's very easy bro. Do you need code? Try yourself once then tell me if you need a code. CHEERS!

Answer (score 2):

`id`s have to be unique. Even if it's in 10 places, `$('#billAmount').text()` will always get the text from the first one: http://jsfiddle.net/48du5ouj/

I'm assuming you have a primary key (Autoincrement ID?) on that table so you can do this:

```
<?php foreach ($h->result() as $row) {?>

<tr id="row-<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
    <td name="billAmount" class="billAmount"><?php echo $row->bill_amount;?></td>

<script>
var bill  = $('$row-<?php echo $row->id; ?> .billAmount').text();
```

Comment: i don't have an A_I in id. joined a new company, they gave me a preloaded database, its a mess! *sigh* @Sergiu Paraschiv

Comment: Try using `foreach($h->result() as $key => $row) {` and use `$key` instead of a `$row->id`. I'm guessing it's an array, so it will have numeric indexes.